# repeat a "copy and reorganize one row" action to a whole spreasheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

thanks to the help of this forum I have been able to do a code which is not so far from what I need.
But the problem is that it do the action only for a row, instead of doing it for all the row on the spreadsheet.

here is the code I did so far :

```
function GENERAL() {
  var Cop = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GO");
  var LP = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("0_Test-LISTE PROJETS");

  var valueRange = LP.getRange('A4:V4').getValues();

  Cop.getRange('A1:F5').setValues([
  [valueRange[0][5], valueRange[0][7], valueRange[0][9], valueRange[0][16], valueRange[0][20], 'duréé projet' /**color red*/],//project lenght
  [valueRange[0][5], valueRange[0][7], valueRange[0][9], valueRange[0][16], valueRange[0][17], 'phase de conception'/**color BLUE*/],//research lenght
  [valueRange[0][5], valueRange[0][7], valueRange[0][9], valueRange[0][17], valueRange[0][17] + ' 7days', 'attente retour BAT'/**color white*/],//waiting for client
  [valueRange[0][5], valueRange[0][7], valueRange[0][9], valueRange[0][17] + ' 7days', valueRange[0][19], 'phase de fabrication'/**color green*/],//production time
  [valueRange[0][5], valueRange[0][7], valueRange[0][9], valueRange[0][19], valueRange[0][20], 'phase installation'/**color purple*/]//installation on site
  ]);
  debugger;
}
```

and now, I want it not only to act on the line "4"  "var valueRange = LP.getRange('A4:V4').getValues();"
but act on every row of the Spreadsheet !

thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to increase the source range of the following script from `A4:V4` to `A4:V`.

  ```
  var valueRange = LP.getRange('A4:V4').getValues();

  Cop.getRange('A1:F5').setValues([
  [valueRange[0][5], valueRange[0][7], valueRange[0][9], valueRange[0][16], valueRange[0][20], 'duréé projet' /**color red*/],//project lenght
  [valueRange[0][5], valueRange[0][7], valueRange[0][9], valueRange[0][16], valueRange[0][17], 'phase de conception'/**color BLUE*/],//research lenght
  [valueRange[0][5], valueRange[0][7], valueRange[0][9], valueRange[0][17], valueRange[0][17] + ' 7days', 'attente retour BAT'/**color white*/],//waiting for client
  [valueRange[0][5], valueRange[0][7], valueRange[0][9], valueRange[0][17] + ' 7days', valueRange[0][19], 'phase de fabrication'/**color green*/],//production time
  [valueRange[0][5], valueRange[0][7], valueRange[0][9], valueRange[0][19], valueRange[0][20], 'phase installation'/**color purple*/]//installation on site
  ]);
  ```

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your array `[,,,]` of `Cop.getRange('A1:F5').setValues([,,,])` is used.

```js
function GENERAL() {
  var Cop = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("GO");
  var LP = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("0_Test-LISTE PROJETS");
  var values = LP.getRange('A4:V' + LP.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var res = values.flatMap(valueRange =>
    [
      [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[16], valueRange[20], 'duréé projet' /**color red*/],//project lenght
      [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[16], valueRange[17], 'phase de conception'/**color BLUE*/],//research lenght
      [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[17], valueRange[17] + ' 7days', 'attente retour BAT'/**color white*/],//waiting for client
      [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[17] + ' 7days', valueRange[19], 'phase de fabrication'/**color green*/],//production time
      [valueRange[5], valueRange[7], valueRange[9], valueRange[19], valueRange[20], 'phase installation'/**color purple*/]//installation on site
    ]
  );
  Cop.getRange(2, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

- If you want to use the source range `A2:V`, please modify `LP.getRange('A4:V' + LP.getLastRow()).getValues()` to `LP.getRange('A2:V' + LP.getLastRow()).getValues()`.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)